# Vectors Dependent or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Am I doin it right?

$3-2x + x^2,6-4x+2x^2 $ in $P2$  Check if they are dependent or not?

I am taking their determinant as written

$| 3-2x\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space 6-4x |$

$|x^2\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space2x^2\space\space\space|$

the determinant is non-zero so they are **Linearly Dependent**

The question is am I taking the determinant right as it is a polynomial and what if I want to use $AX=0$ to check for trivial or non-trivial solutions how will I make A by the given statement i.e $3-2x + x^2,6-4x+2x^2 $ in $P2$

Thanks in advance and I really need to workout on my basic concepts of Linear Algebra :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-zero determinant means that the columns/rows are **Linearly independent**. But taking a determinant is not in general a good way to determine whether vectors are linearly independent (since it only works for $n$ vectors at a time, and since it is computation intensive).

The best way to do it is to take the two vectors you're dealing with and row eliminate. In this case the matrix looks like $$\left[  \begin{matrix} 3 & -2 & 1 \\ 6 & -4 & 2 \end{matrix} \right].$$ When you row eliminate, you can find that this matrix is of rank one (the second row goes away right away).

**Comment:** a good way to remember that row elimination preserves the nullspace (and so can tell you the rank) is that row elimination is left-multiplication by invertible matrices, and so $Mx = 0 \iff E_1 \dotsb E_m Mx = 0$ (since $E_1, \dotsc, E_m$ all have trivial nullspace).

Answer (score 1):

Because $$3-2x + x^2=\frac{1}{2}(6-4x+2x^2) $$
is no hard to see that they are linearly dependent

Comment: can the same concept be used with following **$1,x,x^2$** also in **$P2$**